# Annotate function with input param field value

Tags: python, django, database, orm, model

I have a model

```
class Audiopart(models.Model):
    book_id = models.ForeignKey(Audiobook, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    part_title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    part_text = models.TextField(blank = True, null=True)
    part_reader = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    filename = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path, blank=True)
```

with function

```
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join(
        'audio',
        instance.book_id.folder,
        filename
    )
```

I want to upload files in the directory and save in the database just filename (without path). But not found any way to do it.

So, I make a function for cleaning filename

```
def clear_filename(_filename):
    if '/' in _filename:
        _filename = _filename.split('/')[2]
    return _filename
```

How can I print my objects in view with cleaned filename?

```
def audioparts(request, _book_id):
    all_audioparts = list(Audiopart.objects.filter(book_id=_book_id, published=True).values())
    return JsonResponse(all_audioparts, safe=False)
```

Comment: `request.FILES['filename'].name` maybe?

Comment: "I want to ... save in the database just filename" is wrong. Django needs to save whatever it needs to be able to find the uploaded file (`part.filename.url` for example gives the full url to the file so you can download it). If you want the name of the file, use `os.path.basename(part.filename.name)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're not understanding what the `FileField` is. It's actually for storing **and accessing** the file itself. So your field should not be called `filename` but `file` or `audio_file` or something that describes a **file**.

So when you have an instance of `AudioPart`, e.g. `part`, you can actually access the file directly: `part.filename` is the **file** in your code, not its name.

If you want a method to access just the name of the file, define a `@property` on your model:

```
import os

class AudioPart(Model):
    file = FileField(...)
    ...

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)
```

then `part.file` is the file and `part.filename` is the name of the file. This way you can `read()` the file or return its url so people can download it (`part.file.url`) or manipulate it in other ways.

In your view, you can just loop over your files to add the filename to the list before returning your JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the complete and informative answer! 
Just when I get instance with part = Audiopart.objects.get(pk=_part_id) it work good and I can print part.filename. But in my function audioparts(request, _book_id) I get error "Cannot resolve keyword 'filename' into field."

Comment: You can’t use a property the same way as a field, so you can’t use it to query. As I said in your view you need to use a for-loop or a list comprehension and add the value explicitly to each dictionary.